# pyspark batch data process of Huge data

Tags: pyspark, foreach, batch-processing, azure-eventhub

i have huge data which is more than 10 milions this data can be paritioned by a key in the data frame "partition key"

I want to publish the data in the group of this partition key ,is there a way i do it ?

```
sample data 
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
 

#sample data
   df=sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ('1234567','123 Main St','10SjtT','idk@gmail.com','ecom','direct','1')
    ,('877898','234 Main St','efttrt','ouoiuoiu@gmail.com','fbgfbgf','indirect','2')
    ,('234242','44 fdgfdg St','er','oiuouourt@gmail.com','bbbb','indirect','3')
    ,('543','444 bbtt St','2342reyhr2r','rr@gmail.com','jjjj','indirect','1')
    ,('7887','7777 ddsss St','ygf','wew@gmail.com','uuuu','indirect','2')
    ,('122113','333 cdc St','edc','www@gmail.com','yyyy','indirect','2')]
    ,['cust_id','address','store_id','email','sales_channel','category',"partitionId"])

dff = df.select("partitionId","cust_id","address",to_json(struct("store_id","category","sales_channel","email",struct( "category" ,"email").alias("c_email"))).alias("body"))

dff.select("body").show(10,False)
```

In this data frame the partiion key is "partitionId" which batch the data to half million records and then i can push this half million data records to event hub.

pyspark foreach doesnt gave me more controll to batch and process data for eventhub publish.

Please let me know if any suggestions.

Thanks,
Manoj.

Comment: Does this mean there are 20 unique partition keys because they could batch the Dataframe into 0.5M records? If yes, then collect all the unque values and do a for loop over each unique value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to write data to azure event hub by partitioning based on `partitionId`.

You also need to create event hub with `partition count` 20, because your data has around 20 partition.

```
dff = df.select("partitionId","cust_id","address",to_json(struct("store_id","category","sales_channel","email",struct( "category" ,"email").alias("c_email"))).alias("body"))
fdf = dff.select("partitionId","body")

connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://<your_event_hub>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<access_key_name>;SharedAccessKey=<key>;EntityPath=<event_hub_name>"
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

ds = fdf\
.write.partitionBy("partitionId") \
.format("eventhubs") \
.options(**ehConf) \
.save()
```

Before you running this code install this maven package.

```
com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22
```

[image]

Output:

I checked the results in azure stream analytics preview.

[image]